# Namespace alias scoping issues

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a header file in which I wish to use a namespace alias while defining a class.  However I don't want to expose this alias to anything that includes the header file.

```
// foo.h
namespace qux = boost::std::bar::baz::qux; // ! exposed to the world
class foo
{
    // can't put a namespace alias here

    // stuff using qux::
};
```

How can I alias a namespace for a class declaration without it leaking out everywhere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
namespace MyClassSpace
{
namespace qux = boost::std::bar::baz::qux;

class foo
{
  // use qux::
};

}

using MyClassSpace::foo; // lift 'foo' into the enclosing namespace
```

This is also how most Boost libraries do it, put all their stuff in a seperate namespace and lift the important identifiers into the `boost` namespace.

Comment: @Kerrek: How fitting, I just reached my repcap and need to wait for the reset! :)

Comment: Bastard, I'm desperately trying to make mine in the next two hours ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek: You got way too many accepted answers in one day... anyways, 20 rep missing, eh? Make that 10. :P

Comment: Hehe, nice, thanks! Most of the answers were historical, though -- you know, one of those days. But the upvotes seemed to be hard to come by today... :-)

Comment: Excellent - works just as advertised.  In fact it even does things better than I hoped.  I can lift foo with the using directive, but not lift other things like foohelper.  (Although if I used namespaces routinely in the first place I could already have the same effect).

Comment: @wxffles: Yes, such `foohelper` belong in a `detail` namespace. :)